# expected expression before textString

Tags: c

I'm trying to a make a program that reads from file, sort and count all the unique words into array. I've tested all my methods in the program and they worked but I had a problem with the final test. This is how it looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "WordReader.h"
#include "DataSet.h"
#include "TextString.h"

int main(void)
{
    FILE *input = fopen("text.txt","r");
    WordReader* r = createWordReader(input);
    DataSet* s= createDataSet();

    TextString* nextWord= readNext(r);

    while(nextWord !=0)
    {
         if(!isMember(s, nextWord))
         {
            insert(s, nextWord);     
         }
         TextString* nextWord= readNext(r);`enter code here`
    }

    closeReader(r);

    printf("%d\n", toString(TextString nextWord) +
          "contains" + size(s) + "Distinct Words");

}
```

The things is when i execute the program in cygwin I got the following error on line 27 
It says `expected expression before 'TextString'`. I stared using C language 2 weeks ago and I don't understand it quite well so ask for help.

Comment: Variables need to be declared at the top of a block.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: that hasn't been the case since C99.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is somewhat ambiguous, but to pass a variable as argument to a function you do not need to specify it's type, only the name of the variable. So line 27 should have only **toString(nextWord)**. Also, string concatentation via + does not exist in C, it may exist in C++ if you define an operator. Also objects are not part of C, only C++. String concatenation you can do in a temporary buffer using strcpy() first, then followed by as many strcat() calls as you need. To output a string via printf(), the format parameter should also be "%s\n".

This, however, might not solve all your problems since I don't know what the content of those local headers is or any of the other files used in compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I think statement

```
TextString* nextWord= readNext(r);`enter code here`
```

causes this error.
If `enter code here` is a comment then it should be `//enter code here` otherwise this is not a valid syntax in C.